# Serializing a class containing a custom class

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I want to serialize an object as xml that contains other custom classes. From what I understand (I've been reading MSDN and SO mostly), the `XmlSerializer` doesn't take this into account.

This is the line that's confusing me:

> XML serialization serializes only the public fields and property values of an object into an XML stream. XML serialization does not include type information. For example, if you have a Book object that exists in the Library namespace, there is no guarantee that it will be deserialized into an object of the same type.

Taken from MSDN, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

For example, I want to serialize an object of type `Order`, but it contains a list of `Products`, and each one contains an object of type `Category`:

```
class Order
{
    List<Product> products;
}

class Product
{
    Category type;
}

class Category
{
    string name;
    string description;
}
```

And I want my `Order` object to be serialized like so:

```
<Order>
    <Product>
        <Category Name="">
            <Description></Description>
        </Category>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Category Name="">
            <Description></Description>
        </Category>
    </Product>
<Order>
```

Does the `XmlSerializer` already do this? If not, is there another class that does or do I have to define the serialization process myself?

Comment: It will do it fine. Just redeclare your private fields as public properties with public getters/setters. You can make use of `XmlAttribute` attributes (and others) to ensure that the properties get serialized in the style you want. EDIT: You might also need to make your classes `public`; not sure if `internal` will work or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Order can be seen as a list of Products, a Product as a list of Categories (because it can pertain to multiple categories).

You can try using

```
//...
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
//...

[XmlRoot("Order")]
public class Order
{
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Product", Type = typeof(Product))]
    public List<Product> Products;
}

public class Product
{
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Category", Type = typeof(Category))]
    public List<Category> Categories;
}

public class Category
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string name;

    [XmlElement("Description")]
    public string description;
}
```

The only trade-off is, that the `<Products>` and `<Categories>` (plural) tags will be visible, because the variables are named that way, but from a point of view of parsing the XML afterwards, that's not an issue.
If any other fields show up in your XML that you don't want, you can have `[XmlIgnore()]` precede them.